# Can't import dependency with private keyword in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to import a dependency that use a private keyword in my react project. When I try to start it it yield me an error :

```js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| export class Client {
>   private publicApiClient: PublicApiClient;
|   private privateApiClient: PrivateApiClient;
|   private walletClient: WalletClient;
```

I tried a bunch of babel plugins but nothing to do. What I can do ? Because I can't modify this code as it's part of a dependency.

Thank a lot for your time.

Comment: That's not possible. You can import `Client`, but you can't import an individual property of `Client` (even a public one), because those only exist after you `new` up the class. Can you create a `new Client()` and use that instance of the class to do what you need?

Comment: Yes I have made a new : `const client: any = new Client(web3ClientConfig, baseAccount);` but each time I want to call a method on this (which are public) it throw me the error. I think it's because it loaded the file only if I use a method.

Comment: You see `You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.` when trying to call `client.someFunction()`??

Comment: Yes If I make the new in another file and import it will not yield except when I use it but if I instantiate my client directly in my current file it will yield at me even if I don't use it. I think it's just that it yield when TS import it because sometimes he makes optimizations.

Comment: Just checked the source of the dependency and they use jsx preserve. Maybe I should local build with jsx react ?